# Android: How to copy directories and files recursively from SD card to online server?

Tags: android, copy, synchronization, server

I want to copy my music files and directories from SD card to my private server using an Android application on my phone. I just want a one click option for a synchronization. I am new to Android development. I am developing an app for it. If I get a code sample it will be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: I think the way StackOverflow works is that you try coding something on your own, then if you can't get it to work, post that code here and someone can then help you.

Comment: Okay, I will come up with some code sample. :-) I am newbie here.

Comment: Nobody knows what your private server is or does. At the very least, if you want help with this sort of thing, you need to indicate what protocol you were planning on using for this synchronization. HTTP? FTP? SCP? Git-over-SSH? SMB? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am planning to use HTTPS.

Comment: OK. What on your server will be accepting files as input via HTTPS, and how? Unlike FTP, SCP, Git-over-SSH, and SMB, HTTPS by default is typically used for downloading data, not uploading. HTTPS supports uploading actions (e.g., `PUT`), but either the Web server has to be configured to support that (with appropriate security), or you have to have a Web server or other Web app that will accept the uploads. You would need to explain, completely, what on your server will be accepting changes to files that you are trying to upload from the mobile device.